# brew can't find vim formulae for Mojave

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew, youcompleteme

After upgrading my Macbook to OSX 10.14.2 I am unable to install vim. 
I did do an upgrade of XCode and

```
xcode-select --install
```

after the upgrade to Mojave.

There is a system vim v.8.0 that is provided by Apple, but this does not readily work with the python v.2.7.15 that YouCompleteMe is using.

So the following:

```
brew install vim --with-override-system-vi
```

fails with

```
Error: No available formula with the name "vim"
```

There is a [Homebrew formula for vim](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/vim)
so a missing formulae is not the problem. Also my brew installation is clean:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew cleanup -s
```

were ran with no errors.
Also

```
brew doctor
```

indicated no problems and running:

```
git fsck
```

came up clean.

Git remote:

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew (push)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my particular problem

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core; brew update
```

Discovered it in an issue discussion on Github, [No formulae at all were found in taps #2387](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/2387) posted by MikeMcquaid

Also, I found it necessary to

```
brew unlink python@2
```

in order for YCM to work (that formulae left on my system from Yosemite environment)